# How do I operate a formula on specific rows of a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a massive dataframe of dimension 26000x6 and I want to apply say a simple mathematical operation on groups of specific entries based on unique values of a column. The issue is that I do not know which rows each unique value is in and there are over 3000 unique values in said column. What can I do for this issue? Apologies for being so general. I am not a CS student.

Comment: hi @Aaron Huynh, it is a good practice to provide some examples of your data and the desired output that you are after. this is so that the community is able to replicate your problem and try to solve it. would you be able to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Your question is a little vague but I think I understand what you're asking. Here's a simple example. Given the following DataFrame, df:

```
    A   B
1   4   0
2   2   2
3   4   1
```

You could do something like this:

```
for i in df.itertuples():
    if i.A == 4:
        df.loc[i.Index, 'B'] += 1
```

We're iterating through each row of the DataFrame, and if the value in column 'A' is 4, we add 1 to the value of column 'B' in the same row.